# Printing dates between two other dates on PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying to print dates between two other dates. Here is my code:

```
$begin = date("d/m/y");
$end = date("d/m/y", strtotime("+1 month"));

$i = 0;
while( strtotime($begin) <= strtotime($end) ){

    echo "$begin\n";

    $i++;
    $begin = date("d/m/y", strtotime("+$i day") );

}
```

You can execute the same code here:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/34c4b721553038f585806798121941bee0c66086

For some reason this code is printing just the dates between 25/01/2017 and 31/01/2017 instead of 25/01/2017 and 25/02/2017. I don't know what's wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Dont get me wrong, but why are you using `date()` here? It can be done only with `strtotime()`. And you will call less functions in the iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` doesn't support dates in `d/m/y` format. It treats these dates as `m/d/y`.

To fix your code, use `Y-m-d` format in the first two lines.

On a sidenote, I'd recommend to use `\DateTime` classes to manipulate dates instead of strings and integers. Read more here: https://paulund.co.uk/datetime-php

Comment: So simple!! Thank you my friend. This helped a lot!

Comment: `doesn't support` is not right (`echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01/01/2017'));` works), it is buggy in a way. Test it on the sandbox link. If strtotime doesn't support d/m/y  why are the first dates correct printed. It becomes broken when it comes to month switch.

Comment: Yes, it also works for `strtotime('02/02/2017')`, `strtotime('03/03/2017')` and so on. I'll leave it for you to figure out why.

Comment: And `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01/11/2017'));` `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('12/2/2017'));`,....

Comment: Ok, got it. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$begin = new DateTime();
$end = (new DateTime())->modify('+1 month');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');

$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('d/m/y')."<br/>";
}
```